# What are some ways to display images on server for a Django project? I keep getting 404 errors

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-settings

A current miniproject that I am working on is a personal cocktail "cookbook" website, where I display different drinks, their recipes, my personal notes, images, etc. I configured the code in that when someone clicks on one of the many drinks that are displayed under a base alcohol category, they will be navigated to that one specific drink and be shown its attributes. The only thing that I haven't been able to do is having the server correctly display the image associated with the drink. Whenever I run the server and click on a specific drink, that entries' contents are shown in the correct format, but the image only appears as an icon and the server console keeps giving a 404 not found error. On Django admin, I am able to save images whenever I create a new entry, and VScode shows the correct location as to where the images are stored.

I made sure that libraries like Pillow and Whitenoise have been downloaded. I also checked the MEDIA and STATIC section of my settings.py file to check the path configuration of where the images can be stored and served. But, so far, the server keeps giving a 404 error and only the name of the alt image is displayed. Sometimes, depending on how I configure the path in the settings files, whenever I test it by going on Django admin and submitting a new image for an entry, a whole new folder is created on VScode that stores that new image instead of being uploaded in my current img folder.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Vodka(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ingredients = models.TextField()
    instructions = models.TextField()
    notes = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/img/', default='')
    background = models.TextField(max_length='2000', default='')
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cocktail_book", "media", "img"),]
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'cocktail_book'
```

vodka_display.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<section>
    <h1>{{vodka_entry.name}}</h1>
    <div class="container">
        {% if vodka_entry.image %}
            <img src="{% static vodka_entry.image.url %}" alt="Image">
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <h2>Ingredients</h2>
        <p>{{vodka_entry.ingredients|linebreaks }}</p>
    <h3>Instructions</h3>
        <p>{{vodka_entry.instructions|linebreaks }}</p>
    <h4>Notes</h4>
        <p>{{vodka_entry.notes}}</p>
    <h5>Background</h5>
        <p>{{vodka_entry.background}}</p>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `manage.py runserver`. If you do, there is a [specific code snippet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) to add to your urls.py in order to serve them.

The following goes in your main urls.py.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```